# Powershell Replace Regex Import CSV File

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file named test.csv (C:\testing\test.csv) in this format:

```
File Name,Location,Added (GMT),Created (GMT),Last Modified (GMT),File Size (Bytes),File Size,Extension,Incident Type
10-MB-Test (1).docx,\\blah\Test 3,10/8/2020 21:13,10/8/2020 19:33,10/8/2020 16:26,10723331,10.23 (MB),docx,low_data_discover
10-MB-Test (1).xlsx,\\blah2\Test 3\,10/8/2020 21:14,10/8/2020 19:33,10/8/2020 16:25,9566567,9.12 (MB),xlsx,high_data_discover
1-MB-Test.docx,\\blah3\Test 3\,10/8/2020 21:13,10/8/2020 19:33,10/8/2020 16:37,1045970,1021.46 (KB),docx,medium_data_discover
```

I'm trying to replace trailing "\" characters (if they exist) for values in the Location column with nothing using this Powershell code:

```
$file1 = import-csv -path "C:\testing\test.csv" | % {$_."Location" -replace "\\$",""} | Select-Object * | export-csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\testing\blah.csv"
```

However, when I run the code, the only output I get is a column named "Length" with a numerical value.  Can you assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only sending the new string (updated location) down the pipeline. You can update each location and then export it at the end.

```
$file1 = import-csv -path "C:\testing\test.csv"
$file1 | ForEach-Object {$_.location = $_.location -replace '\\$'}
$file1 | export-csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\testing\blah.csv"
```